# I am needing to do an internal link that is in FAQs on a site using Vue 3 and Inertia.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have an array of content coming from a database that will be displayed on a page as a group of FAQs. Some of the content will have links to other internal pages on the site. How do I link to the pages using Inertia's link component so that a full page refresh doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is returned after using the link. If you return a full view in the response, the page is reloaded. If you return a small JSON object or something else, you can process it without full loading.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).